# Cannot Understand Some Errors in __add__ functions

Tags: python, operator-overloading

When I study the Class in Python. I met the problems as followed:

  1.

```
class Try_int(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return int(self) + int(other)
```

  2.

```
class Try_int(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self + other
```

The first one gives correct answer. But the second one gives infinite recursion.

Why this problem happens?

```
|  __add__(self, value, /)
|      Return self+value.
```

In fact I checked the `add` by `help(int)`. It seems to be the same as Case 2.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as follows:

In your first class, you convert `self` and `other` to `int`. This means that `self + other` delegates to
 `int.__add__(self, other)`. Note that when you called `dir(int)`, what you got was *documentation* and not the actual implementation of the method, which is in C.

The chain of method calls is therefore:

`Try_int.__add__ -> int.__add__`, and `int.__add__` is not recursive.

In your second class, however, you perform no conversion on `self`. This means that when you attempt to perform `self + other`, Python will look for an `__add__` method defined for `self`. However, it is defined in exactly the place you called it from! This results in the following chain of method calls:

`Try_int.__add__ -> Try_int.__add__ -> Try_int.__add__ -> ...`, which is of course an infinite recursion.

Comment: @FanYe if my answer solved your problem, you can accept it so that others who see this question will know that it works